# Push data from backend (python) to JS

Tags: javascript, python

**Front-end part**

I have an AJAX request which is trying to GET data from my back-end handle every second.

If there is any data, I get this data, add it to my HTML page (without reloading), and continue pulling data every second waiting for further changes.

**Back-end part**

I parse web-pages every minute with Celery.

Extract data from them and pass it to an array (that is a trigger for AJAX request that there is new data).

**Question**

It seems to me that there is another solution for this issue.

I don't want to ask for data from JS to back-end. I want to pass data from back-end to JS, when there are any changes. But without page reload.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use Websockets or SSE(server-side-event). Basically it depends on your specific needs but consider:

[websocket](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-websockets-20110929/) - two way data flow. Client can send data to server and vise versa.

> The WebSocket Protocol enables two-way communication between a client 
>   running untrusted code in a controlled environment to a remote host
>   that has opted-in to communications from that code.

Check [python-websockets-example](https://github.com/mattmakai/python-websockets-example) on Git for examples of Websockets.

[SSE](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-eventsource-20110208/) - one way data flow(Server -> Client)

> To enable servers to push data to Web pages over HTTP or using
>   dedicated server-push protocols, this specification introduces the
>   EventSource interface.
>
> Using this API consists of creating an EventSource object and
>   registering an event listener.

[Flask example](https://github.com/jkbrzt/chat/blob/master/app.py) Flask example of SSE.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It's hard for me to carry this knowledge from documentation.
I googled for Server-side events and it seems to me the solution:)

Comment: @Snobby You are welcome. Also added example links.

Answer (score 2):

To the future visitors to this page,

Three main technologies to push data from the server to the clients.

- Long/short polling (client pull)
- WebSockets (server push)
- Server-Sent-Events (server push).

Check [this great article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/sse-websockets-data-flow-http2/) before implementing yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Push API to do that:
https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/

Answer (score -1):

try to use socketio, the backend create an event with data on socketio and your frontend receives the event and download the data

i resolve a similar problem in this way. i call the backend only when a socketio event was create from the backend.

you must setup a socketio server with nodejs,somewhere